# How to split InfoVis Sunburst Label into multiple lines

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, sunburst-diagram

I have created a test file:

http://www.ivangasparetto.com/jit-test/donut.html:

[image]

I would like the labels to go into multiple lines.

I tried to use the suggestion from
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/javascript-information-visualization-toolkit/IMOYhzlJmr4
but the labels are not placed correctly and the rotation was missing.